# visual code set typescript version locally

Tags: node.js, angular, visual-studio-code

I have an angular 4 (cli)/ nodejs app and i use typescript both of two. They are in a same folder, like this:

- app

  -- public

  -- server

And in visuel code I usaly open the root folder (app) to easily edit files in any folder (public, server).

What I need is, how to config visual code to use different typescript versions in public and in server folder?

In public I need typescript 2.3.4 and in server I need 2.4+. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

In general, the client and the server should be different projects. They can be located in the same dir (app in your case), but each project (public and server) should have its own package.json, here you can specify a particular version of tsc in the devDependencies section.

VS Code has an integrated terminal (see the menu View). So you can open two terminals inside the IDE - one in the public dir and another in the server one. Then, if your package.json files have a script command defined as

```
"tsc": "tsc"
```

you can run tsc in each terminal window like this:

```
npm run tsc
```

It'll use the local tsc version defined in the package.json located in the current dir.

Comment: Sorry, tsc works correctly, but vsc IDE show error in the server files, because vsc use 2.3.4 version of typescript, but in the server 2.4+ is used.

Comment: The errors are reported by tsservice, not by the tsc compiler. In your situation, I'd change the VS Code setting to use the newer version of tsserver.js in the "typescript.tsdk" property. See here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript

Comment: yes I already have found this solution, but in this case I have to edit the settings file based on which version I need. And as I sad I would load both folder (public and server), and it no meter which version is setted, i will get error message on console.

Comment: If you use the 2.4 as the default version of tsservice you don't need to change the settings as the project that uses 2.3 will not give you errors.

Comment: rxjs 5 have bad relationship with ts 2.4+ and rxjs 6 in alpha. And in the public project I need it (rxjs 5) for angular.